# How to parse below json response using jackson 2.X? The bracket [ after the result is causing issue

Tags: json, rest, jackson

I am struggling to parse the below json using jackson libraries

{"result":[{"userID":"xyz","firstName":"abc","lastName":"def","vFlag":"false","URL":"xyz://abc.com/cti.do?sysparm_caller=abc%20def&sysparm_caller_phone=+1 800 123 456"}]}

the square bracket after the "result" seems to be causing the issue.
I already have UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE set in my code.
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

If i remove the [] then the json to pojo works fine. Is their any annotation i can use without fiddling around with string manipulations ?

POJO class

```
package com.parse.input;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

@JsonRootName(value = "result")
public class Employee { 
    private String userID = null;
    private String firstName = null;
    private String lastName = null;
    private String vFlag = null;
    private String uRl = null;
    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }
    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getVFlag() {
        return vFlag;
    }
    public void setVFlag(String vipFlag) {
        this.vFlag = vipFlag;
    }
    public String getURL() {
        return uRl;
    }
    public void setURL(String ctiURL) {
        this.uRl = ctiURL;
    }
}
```

======And the Code to invoke REST API and parse the response======

```
Client restClient = Client.create();            
WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(wURL);            
ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)                                             
        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
        .header("EXT_URL", sURL + inputParameter)
        .get(ClientResponse.class);

String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
try {
    System.out.println("Starting to parse the employee response");  
    Employee employee  = mapper.readValue(ouput.toString(), Employee.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Post the code of the pojo.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around it like this.

```
try{
    JSONObject j=new JSONObject(output.toString());
    extractedJsonEmployee = j.getJSONArray("result").get(0).toString();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//Commented out the UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, since i am already taking out the root
Employee employee  = mapper.readValue(extractedJsonEmployee, Employee.class);
```